# Not able to get the config json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I use the following code to use config file and I want to read the values
and I try with the following and I got error **TypeError: undefined is not a function**

This is the json file which I created in folder configuration/config

```
    {
      "ENV": {
        "dev": {
          "PORT": 3050
        },
        "prod": {
          "PORT": 3060
        }
      }
}


config = require('./configuration/config');
```

I try like the following to get the ENV and I got error

```
var env = config.get('ENV');
```

I use this module
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

In **debug** I saw that the config is object with the defined values...

Comment: Should there by comma at "PORT": 3060,  ?

Comment: @wazaaaap- not this is not the problem the json is valid I just remove unnecessary properties for the post...

Comment: Package you are using uses main folder name in require() then filename.object for the get() function.

Comment: @Archer - sorry buy which URL?

Comment: It's okay - I deleted that comment as you added more info that made it irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the module link you provided the config JSON (`default.json`) needs to be in a folder off root called "config". You can then `require` the module config using

```
var config = require('config');
```

and that appears to automatically load the JSON in and parse it.

You can then use the `get` method like you did in your question:

```
var env = config.get('ENV');
```

Comment: Thanks but I already done it and I got diff error Error: Configuration property "ENV" is not defined....

Comment: Works fine for me. I get `{ dev: { PORT: 3050 }, prod: { PORT: 3060 } }` in the console.

Comment: Make sure the config file is called `default.json`.

Comment: That's not cool, Andy. You did a small and incomplete answers, used my information from the other post, and got the right answer check from a newcomer. This is not a war, this a community information hub, and we expect people to act accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong.

You need to have a "config/default.json", based on your root folder.

Then, just:

```
var config = require( 'config' );

var env = config.get( 'ENV' );

console.log( env );
```

config/default.json file:

```
{
  "ENV": {
    "dev": {
      "PORT": 3050
    },
    "prod": {
      "PORT": 3060
    }
  }
}
```

Just tested with you data, it works correctly.

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure if you need to use this module, but if you don't, you can just use something like this:

```
var config = require( './configuration/config.js' );

console.log( config.ENV );
```

And, your config file would be **./configuration/config.js** (mind the .js not .json):

```
module.exports = {
  "ENV": {
    "dev": {
      "PORT": 3050
    },
    "prod": {
      "PORT": 3060
    }
  }
}
```

That's a simple, but efficient, config file.

Comment: I'm getting some downvotes in this, can someone please elaborate? Env vars are better, but this is a simple and efficient config file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the module in the wrong way, you need to do this:

Put a folder called `config` in your app folder, then you should create a file called `default.json` inside that folder. So, it should look like this:

```
yourApp
--config
----default.json
```

the content of `default.json` based in your example should be only this:

```
{
  "ENV": {
    "dev": {
      "PORT": 3050
    },
    "prod": {
      "PORT": 3060
    }
  }
}
```

and then, when you want to use your configuration anywhere you should require the module like this:

```
var config = require('config');
```

and then use your values like this:

```
var devPort = config.get("ENV.dev.port");
```

And sure, you can also do something like this:

```
var config = require('config');
var env = config.get('ENV.dev');
var port = env.port;
```

Remember that is a `JSON`, you can play with the same way you can play with objects.